# How can I share virtual key in DBeaver for other device?

Tags: foreign-key, primary-key, dbeaver

As I know, the virtual key in DBeaver just existed on the client-side (local device), not in real database. I want to share this virtual key for other devices (not only my device). How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.